# Using Pyperclip to copy and paste a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, pyperclip

I am using pyperclip in Python 3.6

If i have a giant 2D array(640X480) how can I copy it in one program and paste it another program using pyperclip copy() and paste() functions.

Comment: Note that pyperclip only works with plain text, so you might consider passing your 2D array to repr() and then passing the returned string to pyperclip.copy(). This will only work if the array contains simple data types (strings, ints, bools, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st program use the following code:

```
pyperclip.copy(array)
```

In the 2nd program use this:

```
array=eval(pyperclip.paste())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array to a JSON string or perhaps a pickle, copy the string, then paste it into the other program. The other program will need to be able to decode the JSON string or pickle.